# Getting string from a DLL string table

Tags: c++, messagebox

```
HMODULE m_LangDll;  

wchar_t* GetString(const int StringID)
{
    wchar_t* nn = {0};
    if (m_LangDll)
    {
        wchar_t temp[2048];
        if(::LoadString(m_LangDll, StringID, temp, 2048))
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"string found", 0, 0);
            nn = temp;
            return nn;
        }
    }

    //assert(s.length() && _T("String not found!"));
    return 0;
}
```

This code works perfectly fine. It returns the string I want no problem.

If I remove the MessageBox(0, L"String Not Found", 0, 0) it dosn't. It returns a random character. Im obviously doing something wrong. I just dont understand how a seemingly un-related call to MessageBox(0,0,0,0) has any influence.

I have tried replacing the MessageBox call with other code. Like allocating more wchar_t* but it seems it has something to do with calling MessageBox.

I have been calling GetString like...

```
MessageBox(0, GetString(101),L"HHHHH", 0);
```

and I get a different bunch of jibberish when i call it like...

```
wchar_t* tempString = GetString(101);
MessageBox(0, tempString, 0, 0);
```

but both of these ways work as long as i don't comment out MessageBox() in GetString

[EDIT]

Thanks for your replies they were all really helpfull.

my code is now

```
wchar_t* GetString(const int StringID)
{
    wchar_t* nn = new wchar_t[2048];
    if (m_LangDll)
    {
        if(::LoadString(m_LangDll, StringID, nn, 2048))
        {       
        return nn;
        }
    }
    delete [] nn;
    //assert(s.length() && _T("String not found!"));
    return 0;
}
```

thanks neagoegab especially.

Just one more question. Why would it be that MessageBox() made the code work?

Comment: temp is on stack... it will be deleted... at }

Comment: in this expression nn = {0}; -> you should use std::nullptr instead of this.

Comment: It is just by chance as the code was ill-formed. Undefined behaviour means anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of a local variable from a function, causing undefined behaviour:

```
nn = temp; // when the function returns temp is out of scope
return nn; // and n is pointing at temp.
```

Return a `std::wstring` instead and use `c_str()` to access the `const wchar_t*` representation.

Answer (score 0):

Your temp variable is on stack... alocate it on heap:

```
HMODULE m_LangDll;  

wchar_t* GetString(const int StringID)
{
    wchar_t* nn = new wchar_t[2048];
    if (m_LangDll)
    {
        if(::LoadString(m_LangDll, StringID, nn, 2048))
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"string found", 0, 0);
            nn = temp;
            return nn;
        }
    }

    delete [] nn;
    //assert(s.length() && _T("String not found!"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, a problem is that GetString() returns a pointer to buffer llocated on the stack ('temp' local variable). Technically, the buffer is invalid after the return